# FileNotFoundError when calling pip in Python subprocess

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen

I need to run some commands that call pip from a python script.
Pip is installed on my machine (running Ubuntu). Simply entering 'pip' in a terminal outputs help for the pip command.

However, trying to call pip from a python script raises an error.
Calling other commands (such as 'ls') from a script works as expected (prints the output one gets from entering the command in a terminal).

I can't seem to make any progress as to why this doesn't work, so any help is greatly appreciated. MWE below:

```
import subprocess

# Prints list of files in cwd
subprocess.Popen(["ls"])

# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pip': 'pip'
subprocess.Popen(["pip"])
```

EDIT: It seems commands I call with Popen generally behave differently compared to when I just run them in a prompt.
For example running 'python --version' shows Python 3.7.4, but if I do `subprocess.Popen(["python", "--version"])`
I get Python 2.7.15+.

Comment: Can you share the output of "whereis pip", please?

Comment: @4turkuaz /home/<username>/anaconda3/bin/pip

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this on Ubuntu yet but had similar experiences on Windows.

Does the following work?

```
subprocess.Popen(["python"])
```

If so, you can try

```
subprocess.Popen(["python", "m", "pip", "list"])

# or my case on windows
subprocess.Popen(["C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\python.exe", "-m", "pip", "list"]
```